# Pinhole Camera Problem!

Tags: visible-light

I was reading slides of a university course and in one of the slides it says

> 1 Eyes/cameras can’t have VERY small holes because that limits the amount of entering light
>
> 2 and diffracts/bends the light

Bending of light(diffraction) only takes place when light goes near the edge of the surface of the object(e.g. water droplets in cloud) but in the case of the camera or eye light passes through the eye lens or camera lens(not near the surface of the lens), refraction takes place instead of diffraction in the case of eye/camera, so my question is how they are saying that if eyes/cameras have very small holes they will diffracts/bends the light?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your question.   But the size of the pupil (which isn't large - but it's much larger than a pinhole) allows more light in.   A pinhole needs to be small because there isn't a lens.   A pupil can be larger because it's a lens.   A camera, larger still cause it only opens for like 1/50th to 1/400th of a second.   But I'm not sure any of that answers your question.

Comment: @userLTK Thanks for your effort! Let me simplify my question - Let's say pupil is of same size as a pinhole, how will diffraction(bending of light) takes place? And will that effect image formed on retina?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You say:

> Bending of light(diffraction) only takes place when light goes near the edge of the surface of the object

and this is broadly correct. Light diffracts when it is near an edge, and the nearer it is to an edge the more it diffracts.

And of course a circular aperture has an edge. The light passing through the centre of the aperture is well away from the edge and doesn't diffract much. However the light that passes near the edge of the aperture will be deflected. With a big aperture most of the light is far from the edge so the percentage of the light that is diffracted by a significant angle is negligable.

[image: Large aperture]

However with a very small aperture a lot of the light is near enough to the edge to be significantly deflected.

[image: Small aperture]

In the far field limit the diffraction due to the aperture produces an [Airy disk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_disk). The angular divergence of the light produced by diffraction is given by:

$$ \sin\theta \approx 1.22\frac{\lambda}{d} $$

where $\lambda$ is the wavelength of the light and $d$ is the diameter of the aperture. You ask about the pupil of the eye. The diameter of the pupil is around 2 to 8 mm depending on the brightness of the light. If we take the smaller size and the wavelength of light to be around 550nm that gives us:

$$ \theta \approx 0.0003 \,\text{radians} \approx 0.02 \,\text{degrees} $$

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply - I have one more question - How diffraction is different from Fresnel diffraction and Fraunhofer diffraction?

Comment: @InderGill: the diffraction pattern changes with distance from the diffracting object. The equation I give applies to the far field limit, i.e. far from the diffracting object, and in this limit the pattern is known Fraunhofer diffraction. As you move nearer the object the pattern changes and this is known as Fresnel diffraction. So they are the same think, just viewed at different distances.